# Can't shuffle playlists and then sync that shuffled playlist to my iPod

Tags: playlist

Can't shuffle playlists and then sync that shuffled playlist to my iPod. I was able to do this in the previous versions of itunes just by clicking a button. That button is not there anymore. How can I shuffle specific playlists and have that shuffled list transfer to my iPod in the shuffled order?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem and I've looked at other websites and it seems that no one can a figure out a way to do it. I think the only option we have is to write to Apple and ask that they bring the feature back.

http://apple.com/feedback/

I already did that and I hope you will too.